# AWS API - Won't accept my Signature

Tags: vb.net, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I've tried everything here, but the Amazon Load Balancer API just will not accept my signature.

Whatever I try, I get a "403 SignatureDoesNotMatch" response. I'm probably missing something obvious, but having spent hours trying to figure out what that is, I'm at the end of my tether. Please help!! Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub DeregisterInstanceFromLoadBalance(ByVal strServerID As String)
    Dim strURL As String
    strURL = "http://elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/?"
    Dim strTimestamp As String = PercentEncodeRfc3986(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))

    Dim strParams As String
    strParams = "AWSAccessKeyId=<MY_API_KEY>" & _
    "&Action=DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer" & _
    "&Instances.member.N=" & strServerID & _
    "&LoadBalancerName=ATTB" & _
    "&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256" & _
    "&SignatureVersion=2" & _
    "&Timestamp=" & strTimestamp & _
    "&Version=2009-05-15"

    Dim strStringToSign As String = "GET\nelasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com\n/\n" & strParams

    strURL = strURL & strParams & "&Signature=" & PercentEncodeRfc3986(HashString(strStringToSign))

    Dim wc As New WebClient()
    Dim strResponse As String
    strResponse = wc.DownloadString(strURL)

End Sub


Private Const PRIVATE_KEY As String = "<MY_PRIVATE_KEY>"

Private Function HashString(ByVal StringToHash As String) As String
    Dim Key() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PRIVATE_KEY)
    Dim XML() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StringToHash)
    Dim myHMACSHA256 As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Key)
    Dim HashCode As Byte() = myHMACSHA256.ComputeHash(XML)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(HashCode)
End Function


Private Function PercentEncodeRfc3986(ByVal str As String) As String

    str = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    str = str.Replace("'", "%27").Replace("(", "%28").Replace(")", "%29").Replace("*", "%2A").Replace("!", "%21").Replace("%7e", "~").Replace("+", "%20").Replace("%7E", "~")

    Dim sbuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(str)
    For i As Int32 = 0 To sbuilder.Length - 1

        If sbuilder(i) = "%" Then
            If (Char.IsLetter(sbuilder(i + 1)) OrElse Char.IsLetter(sbuilder(i + 2))) Then
                sbuilder(i + 1) = Char.ToUpper(sbuilder(i + 1))
                sbuilder(i + 2) = Char.ToUpper(sbuilder(i + 2))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return sbuilder.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got to the bottom of this. There were a few problems; not least Amazon's documentation.

- In VB.Net, I should have been using **ControlChars.Lf** rather than **"\n"**
- The **Instances.member.N** parameter as documented 
  is just wrong, it should be
  **Instances.member.[N].InstanceId**, where [N] is the instance index,
  starting at **1**. This was returning
  the rather confusing error message
  "LoadBalancerNotFound".
- The correct domain is **elasticloadbalancing.[availability_zone].amazonaws.com**; the examples used in the docs don't make this particularly clear either. (although domain usage is documented elsewhere)